# How to set all values below point ( TileMap like array)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've tried alot of different solutions, 
but im not quite sure if its the problem
with my methods or if the code doesnting work

For example,

I want to be able to set the values in the array below in the value im orginally setting heres my attempt

```
function makepointfrom(x,y,size)
{
      for(var y2= y;y2 < size;y2++)
      {
        tilemap[x][y2] = num;
      }
}
var tilemap = 
[
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
]
makepointfrom(2,0,4);
```

Expected output

```
var tilemap = 
[
 [0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,0,0],
]
```

Not

```
var tilemap = 
[
 [0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to swich `x` and `y`, because `x` is the row. Then I suggest to use an offset and use the sum for accessing the element.

```js
function makepointfrom(x, y, size) {
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (!tilemap[x + i]) continue;
        tilemap[x + i][y] = 1;
    }
}
var tilemap = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

makepointfrom(0, 2, 4);

tilemap.map(a => console.log(...a));
```

Answer (score 0):

x = innerArray index

y = outer array index from which we need to start

size = tilemap size

```js
function makepointfrom(x,y,size)
{
      for(var y2= y;y2 < size;y2++)
      {
        tilemap[y2][x] = 1;
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(tilemap))
}
var tilemap = 
[
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
]
makepointfrom(2,0,tilemap.length);
```